# [Fixed ]Trying to avoid repetitive CSS by declaring with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JS/Jquery so please be nice.

Basically, a website I'm working on has a map containing several numbered markers. From 1 to 28. The markers are all made up of one background image sprite, with background-position declarations for each number.

I'd usually create a CSS sprite and use background-position and class names to show the correct number marker.

But as there's 28 markers, it's very tiresome to plot exact background positions for each marker.

I'm playing around with this code I made;

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/6Mn9Z/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="label-1">
This label 1
</div>

<div class="label-2">
This label 2
</div>
```

JS:

```
var label = '1';
var pos = '0';

while (label <= 28){
$(".label-" + label).css('background-position-x',pos + 'px');
label = label + 1;
pos = pos + 14;
};
```

I'm trying to get the script to assign the new background-position CSS rule for each label (.label-#), which changes on each run of the loop. If that makes sense.

So on the second run of the loop, background-position-x gives 14px. And that css is applied to .label-2.

I feel like I'm nearly there, but missing something out.

Many thanks.

EDIT: For future reference, don't use background-position-x as it doesn't work in Firefox. Use background-position instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Mn9Z/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the label counter as a string. Adding 1 to it will result in actually concatenating it, so the second value of the label is '11'.

Fix:

```
var label = 1;
```

Don't worry, it will be converted properly to string in the selector.

(same for position)

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var label = '1'; //string
var pos = '0'; //string
```

to

```
var label = 1; //integer
var pos = 0; //integer
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/6Mn9Z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
var label = '1';
var pos = '0';
```

for

```
var label = 1;
var pos = 0;
```

You are trying to add strings so '1' + 1 = 11

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complicated (and generic) way of doing it is to:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xG27g/2/)

Give all the elements the same class and a class for identifying the label position:

```
<div class="label label-1">This label 1</div>
<div class="label label-2">This label 2</div>
```

Then loop over the elements using `.each()` in jQuery. If the labels are in ascending order then you can simply do this (ignoring the `label-*` class):

```
$( '.label' ).each( function(i){
       $( this ).css( 'background-position-x', (14*i) + 'px' );
});
```

If the labels are not in ascending order (or if you skip over a label) then you can loop over them and extract the label values with a regular expression:

```
$( '.label' ).each( function(i){
       var t = $(this),
           p = parseInt( t.attr( 'class' ).match( /\blabel-(\d+)\b/ )[1] );
       if ( !isNaN( p ) )
       {
           t.css( 'background-position-x', (14*(p-1)) + 'px' );
           console.log( i + ": " + p );
       }
});
```